# can AesCryptoServiceProvider do parallel decryption in CBC mode?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

I would like to perform parallel decryption function using AesCryptoServiceProvider in CBC mode.  I am able to decrypt with no problem sequentially but I can't figure out how to manually perform XOR operations during the decryption process using AesCryptoServiceProvider.

Comment: If you want to do encryption or decryption in parallel then using CTR mode is generally easier.

Answer (score 0):

In general yes. Break the encryption on a block boundaries, use the same key, for the first part use the same IV as was used for encryption, for additional part use the last encrypted block of the previous part for the IV.

See [CBC Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

Note that this may not be faster based on the chip-set and/or hardware encryption available. Hardware encryption can be 1000 times faster than software.